# I have a textbox with with browse option which saves the path to which I have to save the text file and a combobox

Tags: c#

I have a textbox and a combobox. In textbox it has a browse button to select the location where I can save the text file and a size combo box where I have 5 options 512KB , 1MB , 2MB, 3MB , 4MB, 5 MB. When I select location and size from combo box it should save the string path and limit of size in database but it should save the  size in INT datatype and if 1 mb is selected from combobox it should the value 1024 with int datatype in desktop what should be the code ?

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you have so that it is easier to assist or point out where you may be going wrong?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add your code to the question.

Comment: Still SO haven't started code writing services

Comment: i have uploaded the link. of the image

Comment: just make a if or switch and then save it in your database. what's the problem exactly? we need to see some code to help you.

Comment: the problem is 512 kb is string but when i click it ok it sould save it as an integer convert it to int and save 512 in to database.

Comment: @AashirKhan why is that still a problem after I told you how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use Long Preferable

```
static double ConvertBytesToMegabytes(long bytes)
{
    return (bytes / 1024f) / 1024f;
}

static double ConvertKilobytesToMegabytes(long kilobytes)
{
    return kilobytes / 1024f;
}
```

[Reference Take](https://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-bytes-megabytes)